# Blur image within a circle openCV

Tags: java, opencv

So I process the image to find my desired object. As a result I get an image something like this.
[image]

```
Imgproc.drawContours(subImage, contours, i, new Scalar(r, g, b));
Core.circle(subImage, point, 10, new Scalar(255, 0, 0));
```

Now I need to  blur the content of red circles. Code for blurring.

```
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mask, mask, new Size(55, 55), BLUR_STR);
```

I know their center point and radius. I guess I have to take `submat` from my `subImage` which is type `Mat` but I have not found a way to take a circular submat from image using only center point and radius.

Anyone know a way?

When using @Micka idea I get a lot of background noise with the mask.
[image]

```
Mat mask = new Mat(subImage.size(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
Core.circle(subImage, point, radius, new Scalar(224, 224, 224, 10), -1);
Mat blurredImage = new Mat();
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(subImage, blurredImage, new Size(55, 55), BLUR_STR);
blurredImage.copyTo(subImage, mask);
```

Comment: draw each red circle filled on an empty image (to get a mask). Then blur whole image to a new temporary image. Then copy back to the original image all pixel where the mask isnt zero.